# std::cout is not printing

Tags: c++, printing, output

When I print out using `std::cout`, it doesn't print anything to the terminal:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string multiplystr(std::string string, int mult) {
    for (int i = 1; i < mult; i++)     {
        string = string + string;
    }
    return string;
}

class entry {
public:

    entry(int width) {
        int frameWidth = width;
    }

    int frameWidth;
    std::string framechar = "-";

    std::string frame = multiplystr(framechar, (frameWidth + 4));
    std::string justout = frame + '\n';
};

int main() {
    entry x1(15);
    std::string out1 = x1.frame;
    std::cout.flush();
    cout << "out1" << std::endl;
}
```

However, if I delete everything except the print statement, it prints properly. Do you know why it does this?

I also used `std::flush` and it does not work.

Comment: A proper constructor would be `entry(int width) : framewidth(width) { }`

Comment: While fixing the indentation in the code, my tools complained about the constructor: *Member 'frameWidth' was not initialized in this constructor*, echoing Johnny Mopp's second comment. Good tools can help you spot mistakes.

Comment: Whoop. Johnny's comment vanished.

Comment: I had a mistake in my comment stating `frameWidth` would be default initialized to `0`, but it is actually uninitialized since it is on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has **undefined behavior**, so literally *anything* could happen <sup>1</sup>.

In your `entry` class, the constructor body is assigning its input `width` value to a *local variable* named `frameWidth` which *shadows* the class member of the same name. As such, the `frameWidth` member is never initialized.

You are then passing the `frameWidth` member to the `mult` parameter of `multiplystr()` when initializing the `frame` member.  The `frame` member is initialized *before* the constructor body begins running, so even if you fixed the constructor body to get rid of the local variable and assign the `width` value to the `frameWidth` member correctly, by then it is too late, the damage has already been done.

<sup>1</sup>: In my test, when I run the code, I get a runtime error before the print statement is reached, because `mult` ends up being a very large value that causes the loop to blow up available memory.

To fix that, you need to initialize the `frameWidth` member in the constructor's [initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) instead of the constructor body. The initialization list will initialize `frameWidth` before the `frame` member is initialized, and thus before `multiplystr()` is called.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string multiplystr(std::string s, int mult) {
    for (int i = 1; i < mult; i++)     {
        s += s;
    }
    return s;
}

class entry {
public:

    entry(int width) : frameWidth(width) {}

    int frameWidth;
    std::string framechar = "-";

    std::string frame = multiplystr(framechar, (frameWidth + 4));
    std::string justout = frame + '\n';
};

int main() {
    entry x1(15);
    std::string out1 = x1.frame;
    std::cout << "out1 = " << out1 << std::endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7Xn7v3)

Comment: Modify the last line. You are outputting  out1 as a string and not as a variable.

Comment: @PranavMare Why?

Comment: Modify the last line. You are outputting out1 as a string and not as a variable.

Comment: @PranavMare because the OP's original code was doing that. It doesn't matter WHAT is printed, my example proves that the print statement is actually reached, and actually outputs *something* to the terminal. That is the important thing. In the OP's code, the print statement is not reached, which is why nothing prints to the terminal. But whatever, I have updated my example.